# Can I use a Chainlink Function to dowload a file?

Tags: solidity, dapps, chainlink

I found this example Chainlink Function https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/API-request-example.js:

```
// This example shows how to make a decentralized price feed using multiple APIs

// Arguments can be provided when a request is initated on-chain and used in the request source code as shown below
const coinMarketCapCoinId = args[0]
const coinGeckoCoinId = args[1]
const coinPaprikaCoinId = args[2]
const badApiCoinId = args[3]

if (
  secrets.apiKey == "" ||
  secrets.apiKey === "Your coinmarketcap API key (get a free one: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/)"
) {
  throw Error(
    "COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY environment variable not set for CoinMarketCap API.  Get a free key from https://coinmarketcap.com/api/"
  )
}

// To make an HTTP request, use the Functions.makeHttpRequest function
// Functions.makeHttpRequest function parameters:
// - url
// - method (optional, defaults to 'GET')
// - headers: headers supplied as an object (optional)
// - params: URL query parameters supplied as an object (optional)
// - data: request body supplied as an object (optional)
// - timeout: maximum request duration in ms (optional, defaults to 10000ms)
// - responseType: expected response type (optional, defaults to 'json')

// Use multiple APIs & aggregate the results to enhance decentralization
const coinMarketCapRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?convert=USD&id=${coinMarketCapCoinId}`,
  // Get a free API key from https://coinmarketcap.com/api/
  headers: { "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": secrets.apiKey },
})
const coinGeckoRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coinGeckoCoinId}&vs_currencies=usd`,
})
const coinPaprikaRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers/${coinPaprikaCoinId}`,
})
// This dummy request simulates a failed API request
const badApiRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: `https://badapi.com/price/symbol/${badApiCoinId}`,
})

// First, execute all the API requests are executed concurrently, then wait for the responses
const [coinMarketCapResponse, coinGeckoResponse, coinPaprikaResponse, badApiResponse] = await Promise.all([
  coinMarketCapRequest,
  coinGeckoRequest,
  coinPaprikaRequest,
  badApiRequest,
])

const prices = []

if (!coinMarketCapResponse.error) {
  prices.push(coinMarketCapResponse.data.data[coinMarketCapCoinId].quote.USD.price)
} else {
  console.log("CoinMarketCap Error")
}
if (!coinGeckoResponse.error) {
  prices.push(coinGeckoResponse.data[coinGeckoCoinId].usd)
} else {
  console.log("CoinGecko Error")
}
if (!coinPaprikaResponse.error) {
  prices.push(coinPaprikaResponse.data.quotes.USD.price)
} else {
  console.log("CoinPaprika Error")
}
// A single failed API request does not cause the whole request to fail
if (!badApiResponse.error) {
  prices.push(httpResponses[3].data.price.usd)
} else {
  console.log(
    "Bad API request failed. (This message is expected to demonstrate using console.log for debugging locally with the simulator)"
  )
}

// At least 3 out of 4 prices are needed to aggregate the median price
if (prices.length < 3) {
  // If an error is thrown, it will be returned back to the smart contract
  throw Error("More than 1 API failed")
}

const medianPrice = prices.sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.round(prices.length / 2)]
console.log(`Median Bitcoin price: $${medianPrice.toFixed(2)}`)

// The source code MUST return a Buffer or the request will return an error message
// Use one of the following functions to convert to a Buffer representing the response bytes that are returned to the client smart contract:
// - Functions.encodeUint256
// - Functions.encodeInt256
// - Functions.encodeString
// Or return a custom Buffer for a custom byte encoding
return Functions.encodeUint256(Math.round(medianPrice * 100))
```

This function just fetches the price of bitcoin. Could I use a Chainlink function to download a file from IPFS? If so, what would it look like?

Comment: Hey,  as the Chainlink functions return the data to the contract, what are you trying to achieve after downloading the IPFS file?

Comment: I want the CID of the file to be hidden. If the static site just links to the file in the page the CID will be visible. The file will be part of an IPFS folder so the CID of the folder won't be able to be calculated from the downloaded file.

Comment: So basically ,you want to use the chainlink function to reveal the CID and bring it on-chain?

Comment: No, the function keeps the CID hidden. I don't want anything being brought on chain. The Chainlink function just goes and gets the payload from IPFS and delivers it to the browser.

Comment: Maximum return zie from Chainlink functions id 256 bytes. https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/api-custom-response

Comment: Oh darn, thanks for the answer. I guess it's not possible to stream a file to the browser unless it's really small lol.